# Calculate loss from intermediate layer

Tags: neural-networks

Say I have an intermediate embedding layer (say at first layer) in a neural network of four layers. A desired property of the embedding matrix is that the sparser the better. Say the output from neural network is o1, is it ok to make the score like
score(o1)+sparse(embedding matrix)? That is we not only use the final output, also the intermediate embedding layer (intermediate output)?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, it's Okay. That's common method for handling mid-layer distribution.
See this nice example. It forces mid-layer distribution to maintain similarity between input data of two different domain.
(https://github.com/haeusser/learning_by_association/tree/master/semisup)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality 
statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
link-only answers, due to linkrot. Could you 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link?